# Get all node-relation originating from a node in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say we have this cypher

```
match (n:Person{pid:322})-[k*1..2]->(s) return k
```

`k` would be a `Collection` of all relation originating from a specific node `n` in at most 2 hops.

How can I get all `Node-Relation-Node` where `Relation` is in `k`? It's something like `match (a)-[b]->(c) foreach b in k return a,b,c` but I know this query is invalid since `foreach` keyword in Neo4J can't be used in this case.

Edit:
I think I should add some illustration to make things clearer. Here I use an example from Neo4J documentation:
[image: Neo4J example]

When I start from Charlie Sheen and using 1..2 range, the query must return (assuming the query ends with `return a,b,c`)

a          |     b    |      c
Charlie Sheen | ACTED_IN | Wall Street
Charlie Sheen | FATHER   | Martin Sheen
Martin Sheen  | ACTED_IN | The American President
Martin Sheen  | ACTED_IN | Wall Street

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should produce the `a`, `b`, and `c` values your edited question asks for (assuming you always want the `name` property values):

```
MATCH (n:Person{pid:322})-[k*1..2]->(s)
WITH LAST(k) AS lk
RETURN STARTNODE(lk).name AS a, TYPE(lk) AS b, ENDNODE(lk).name AS c;
```

Comment: Perfect! Never heard about `LAST` function, even after I looked it up in the docs, I still can't comprehend why it can be used in this case. Mind to explain?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that wouldn't just be:

```
match (n:Person{pid:322})-[k*1..2]->(s) return n,k,s
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Nope, in your case the `n` will always be that Node with pid 322. But actually `k` may contain outgoing relation NOT from `n`

Comment: Yeah, I thought that's what he was looking for from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

A path will give you the sequence of nodes and relationsjips from `n` to `s` via `k`

```
 MATCH p=(n:Person{pid:322})-[k*1..2]->(s) return p
```

You can also extract only the nodes and/or only the relationships from the path using `nodes(p)` or `rels(p)`